# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type ''"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I got a real head scratcher!! I've been trying to figure this out but to no avail!

Error: Type '{ fieldHandler: (e: any) => void; getBrands: Function; brands: Brands[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'BrandProps': error, errorHandler, nav, navHandler  TS2739

I have a Parent component passing props to a child component, and a  higher order component passing additional props to that same child component.

Parent component return

```
return (
    <Fragment>
      <Brands
        fieldHandler={fieldHandler}
        getBrands={get_brands}
        brands={brands}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Higher order component

```
export type WrapperProps = {
  error?: boolean;
  errorHandler?: Function;
  nav?: object;
  navHandler?: Function;
};

const stepsHoc = <P extends WrapperProps>(
  OriginalComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.FunctionComponent<P> => {
  const NewComponent: React.FC<P & WrapperProps> = props => {
    const [error, errorHandler] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [nav, navHandler] = useState<object>({
      next: null,
      previous: null
    });

    return (
      <OriginalComponent
        error={error}
        errorState={errorHandler}
        nav={nav}
        navHandler={navHandler}
        {...(props as P)}
      />
    );
  };
  return NewComponent;
};

export default stepsHoc;
```

Child component

```
interface IBrand {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface BrandProps {
  error: boolean;
  errorHandler: Function;
  nav: object;
  navHandler: Function;
  fieldHandler: Function;
  getBrands: Function;
  brands: IBrand[];
}

const Brands: React.FC<BrandProps> = ({
  fieldHandler,
  getBrands,
  brands,
  error,
  errorHandler,
  nav,
  navHandler
}) => {

// * Note logging of error in child = false 
  console.log('Log = ', error); 

  return (
    <Fragment>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default StepsHoc(Brands);
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: Exactly! haha the error I'm getting seems to suggest that error, errorHandler, nav, navHandler are not properties of  BrandProps.

Comment: so your higher order component is passing props to parent component and parent component is passing props to child component, is that correct?

Comment: Parent is passing props to HOC, and HOC is passing additional props to child. HOC is just a "wrapper" around child component.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, that might help. Also, I noticed a typo error, see your HOC OriginalComponent props: `errorState={errorHandler}`, guess that should be `errorHandler` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here are the props you are passing down to your child component.

As defined in your child, these are the props the component has to receive:

```js
interface BrandProps {
  error: boolean;
  errorHandler: Function;
  nav: object;
  navHandler: Function;
  fieldHandler: Function;
  getBrands: Function;
  brands: IBrand[];
}
```

While in your parent component, you are only passing 3 of them:

```js
<Brands
        fieldHandler={fieldHandler}
        getBrands={get_brands}
        brands={brands}
      />
```

And in the HOC the extra properties can be optional (so they may not exist, reason why it errors).

So to fix, you can just set the extra properties on your `BrandProps` interface as optional by defining them with "?", such as `error?: boolean;`, or you can just add them in if you think they must be passed